# NameError: name 'transforms' is not defined, while using google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, mnist, torchvision

```
train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True,transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True,transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))`
```

After executing this on colab notebook, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b81aa6cf1cbe> in <module>()
----> 1 train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True,transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
      2 test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True,transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

NameError: name 'transforms' is not defined*
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be defined? Did you import it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing from the context that you're using Pytorch, in which case you need to make sure you have:

```
from torchvision import transforms
```

In your imports. By the looks of things you have already imported `datasets` from the same library.